# Decrypting a Linux/Ubuntu encryptedfs?

Tags: linux, encryption

I have an image of a linux machine with an encryptedfs  (/home/.private, etc). Is it possible to export the file structure and mount it from a different linux box/VM?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes.

The long answer is you need more information on what distro/version the image is of, as there are a number of different ways to create an encrypted filesystem on linux.

If it's an ubuntu system, boot it up and `man ecryptfs` if you get a page, then the ecryptfs-utils package is installed, in which case it's very likely that that is what was used, and you can mount the private share with mount as described on the ecryptfs manpage.

Comment: and you'll have to have the appropriate "encryption keys"

Comment: tkrabec is right, if you don't have the passwords/keys, then the answer is actually a resounding NO. but the question was how to mount, not how to crack.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [eMount](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emount/) which [this artice](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/emount-mount-encrypt-and-manage-disk-image-filesphysical-disk-drives.html) suggests will do this kind of thing.

- Mount system partitions and virtual disks from the GUI or command line. The source can be plain or encrypted. List of supported file systems is O/S dependent. ISO images are widely supported.